# «Впрочем» – союз или вводное слово?

Tags: союзы, вводные-слова, части-речи

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой части речи выделенное слово (союз это или вводное слово):

"**Впрочем**, хозяйство было простое: в одном углу чердака лежала картошка, в другом — свёкла и капуста, лук и соль".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без контекста бывает трудно понять, к какой части речи отнести "впрочем".

*А как ловко хозяйничала она в свои семь лет! **Впрочем,** хозяйство было простое: в одном углу чердака лежала картошка, в другом – свёкла, капуста, лук и соль. За хлебом мы ходили к Петровне* (Вениамин Каверин. Два капитана).

В данном случае это союз. Можно заменить, например, на "хотя" или "но".

> **ВПРОЧЕМ,** *вводное слово и союз*
> <...>
> 2. Союз. Соединяет предложения или части сложного предложения. Сближаясь по значению с вводным словом, союз «впрочем» отделяется запятой (реже тире) от последующей части предложения.
>
> *Акакий Акакиевич начал было отговариваться, но все стали говорить, что неучтиво, что просто стыд и срам, и он уж никак не мог отказаться. **Впрочем,** ему потом сделалось приятно, когда вспомнил, что он будет иметь чрез то случай пройтись даже и ввечеру в новой шинели.* Н. Гоголь, Шинель. *Я всей душой желал быть тем, чем вы хотели бы, чтоб я был; но я ни в ком никогда не находил помощи... **Впрочем,** я сам прежде всего виноват во всём.* Л. Толстой, Война и мир. *Сегодня был председатель домкома, разбирал жалобу на собаку. Победил Бим. **Впрочем,** гость мой судил как Соломон.* Г. Троепольский, Белый Бим Черное Ухо. *Дом-то небольшой, они там как пиявки в банке; **впрочем,** общий обеденный стол довольно хороший и вино петербургское.* И. Панаев, Раздел имения. *Сделайте вечерний чай и, пожалуйста, без вина и без закусок; **впрочем,** я сама всё устрою.* Ф.  Достоевский, Бесы. *Сотни мух густо жужжали под потолком; **впрочем,** в комнате было прохладно…* И. Тургенев, Степной король Лир. *Тихо в городе. **Впрочем** – где-то шаркает метла дворника, чирикают только что проснувшиеся воробьи.* М. Горький, Мои университеты.

Источник: [Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_107).

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @MuratSebert  Спасибо за вопрос!

Comment: А не ошибка ли на Грамоте? *Сближаясь, отделяется.* Отделяется же не сам, люди отделяют. А пассивный залог нельзя.